# Rotate on hover then stay in that position when clicked, return to original position when clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to have an image rotate 180 degrees on hover.  When the image is clicked/selected I'd like the image to remain in that position until it is selected again when it should return to its original position.

I've tried a combination of CSS which works fine for the hover but won't persist.  I then found a few posts using jQuery but don't understand it enough to make the image return when selected again as the example I found was very basic.

The HTML

```
<div class="conversionFormE" id="switch1">
  <label class="swapHide">Swap?</label>
  <input type="button" class="rotate" id="switch" name="switch" value="" onclick="switchUnits()"/>
</div>
```

Some of the CSS

```
.rotate {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;

  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  transition-property: transform;

  overflow:hidden;
}

.rotate:hover {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: onClick function as requested.

```
function switchUnits(){

//need to get values before swap to and from around.
var from = $("#from").val();
var to = $("#to").val();

//switches the details
$("#to #"+from).attr("selected","selected");
$("#from #"+to).attr("selected","selected");

//gets values after switch
from = $("#from").val();
to = $("#to").val();

//run convert
convertUnits();
}
```

EDIT:  Would very much like for this to be achieved:
Possible for image to rotate on hover again back to it's original position without the need for clicking it? so it would be:

in posA, hover, rotate, click, stay in posB. 
in posB, hover, rotate back, click, stay in posA again.

Comment: the `onclick="switchUnits()"` attribute points to a javascript function, you should include this function's code in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just add a selector like `.rotate.rotated` to your css `.rotate:hover`. This way the styling will also get applied when there is an additional class `rotated` present.

Now you can add the following jQuery to toggle that class on click:

```
$('.rotate').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('rotated');
});
```

And an example: http://jsfiddle.net/MZhG5/

Comment: Fiddle works perfectly but when I use the code it still doesn't 'stick' or stay once clicked?

Comment: are you including jQuery? Do you get any errors in the console of your browser?

Comment: no errors at all, jquery is included but it does look like it's not being called?! Moved the function into the file that has the other functions in as I know that works an it didn't work there, then moved it into the main file and still no joy?!

Comment: did you put it inside a `$(document).ready` block or similar, to ensure the DOM is ready? Does the `rotated` class get added after click when you inspect the code?

Comment: oops:) There's a chance I'm a bit of a newbie with jquery.  I put it inside the document.ready and it works great! :) THanks!

Comment: Um...would it now be possible for it to rotate on hover again back to it's original position without the need for clicking it?

so it would be.
in posA, hover, rotate, click, stay in posB.
in posB, hover, rotate back, click, stay in posA again.

Comment: sure you can, have a look at this altered css: http://jsfiddle.net/MZhG5/1/ The effect gets a bit weird do, as it will try to rotate back as soon as you click it. Not sure what behaviour you want exactly, but I think you'll get the idea

Comment: that does get a bit odd but i do see what you mean.  THanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
var clicked = 0;
$(".rotate").click(function () {
   clicked++;
   if (clicked == 1) {
       $(this).addClass("stay");
   }
}).bind("mouseout", function () {
    if (clicked == 2) {
        $(this).removeClass("stay").addClass('normal');
        clicked = 0;
    }
});
```

The CSS:

```
.rotate:hover, .stay {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(180deg);
}
.normal {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg)!important;
    -moz-transform:rotate(0deg)!important;
    -o-transform:rotate(0deg)!important;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ScSHm/

Comment: Hi, It doesn't remain in position once clicked?

Comment: My way is a little over complicated though. Compared to @PeterVR

Comment: Over complicated:) I'm new to jquery, eveyrthing is overcomplicated at the moment